# Uniform Hashing Function for a dynamic hash table

Tags: c++, hash, hashtable

I'm trying to write a simple integer Hash Table class. I want it to be dynamic in the sense that when it's full it'll double itself in size.
I can't seem to find a hashing function that'll work properly. I've tried double hashing with the following function ( but it didn't work ):
h(k)=(x%7 +1+ k*(x%5))%(Table_Size)

Any good one's I'm missing that will work?

Comment: Why didnt it work and what is `x`?

Comment: Good hashing functions are very difficult to come up with. I am assuming you are looking for a hash table which truly supports `O(1)` operations? Then you will need a randomized (yet, deterministic) set of hash functions to actually achieve this (theoretically).

Comment: Yes I want to achieve the O(1) operations. 
So the only option I have without using universal hashing will be to use chain hashing to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

For simple integers, don't hash the number itself (you're not going to generate any nice new properties by doing so), instead use prime numbers for the size of your hash table (this will provide a good uniform distribution for your entries).. in general using prime numbers for your hash table size is a good practice, regardless of what and how you're hashing.

Check out

http://planetmath.org/GoodHashTablePrimes.html

for a list of good sizes to use as your table grows.

Comment: But I'll also need to find those prime numbers. Won't that hurt the amortized complexity of the rehashing?

Comment: Not really, it's a fairly short list for all the numbers you'll need, so you just store the list as a static array and walk it when you need to grow. The cost of doing that is very minimal compared to the reindexing you'll need to do when changing the size of your hash table. And the distribution of the table is great when you use this method, so you'll quickly make up for that little for loop when you're looking up entries :)

Comment: But if I need a hash table that's bigger than that it won't work though. I need something that'll always work.

Comment: It's not hard to extend that list if you really need hash tables with more than several billion records.. which you're already talking about using more ram than is commonly available on modern machines. But say you do, then extend the table by finding the next prime in that sequence by picking primes between 2^n and 2^(n+1) up to as big a number as you will ever need, something like 2^64 for instance..

Comment: Regardless of what you end up doing though, don't hash integers, it doesn't do you any good. The only reason to hash something is to change it into an integer with as much probability of making them equally distributed as possible.. but you already have that characteristic if you are given an integer! (x will always hash to the same h(x) after all..)

Comment: I don't think maintaining a list of primes is practical. `x/ln(x)` primes which are `<= x`. For x = 2^16, which is absolutely possible for some application, that's about 5.9k numbers, which already implies a few dozen kilobyte of overhead. For larger hash tables, it gets progressively worse (if I'm not mistaken, `log_a x = log_b x / log_b a` implies that it grows by roughly 1.69 every time you double the maximum size).

Comment: @delnan you don't need every prime number, when you grow a hash table you typically about double the size of the table.. so you just need the primes that are close to those sizes. You literally want to use the numbers on that list I provided, ie you only need to store the 25 primes listed there.. it's a very small list, and very practical :)